# Cannot find symbol for method

Tags: c#, oop, methods, cannot-find-symbol

I have never had this problem before, I don't know why it is doing this. I am trying to call on method.calcTonsCO2();
but it is giving me a cannot find symbol error. I know the method exists and i am not making any typos... Whats going on

Main method tester:

```
public class CO2FootprintV1Tester
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        //declaration of variables
        double gals, tons, pounds;

        //initialization        
        CO2FootprintV1Tester footprint = new CO2FootprintV1Tester();

        //methods
        footprint.calcTonsCO2();
        footprint5.convertTonsToPoundsCO2();
        tons = footprint.getTonsCO2();
        pounds = footprint.getPoundsCO2();
    }
}
```

Main Method Class:

```
public class CO2FootprintV1
{   
    //declaration of private instance variables
    private double myGallonsUsed; 
    private double myTonsCO2;
    private double myPoundsCO2;

    /**
     * Constructor for ojbects of type CO2FootPrintV1
     * @param gals are gallons used
     * 
     */

    CO2FootprintV1 (double gals)
    {        
        myGallonsUsed = gals;
    }

    /**
     *  Method to calculate tons of CO2
     */
    public void calcTonsCO2()
    {
        myTonsCO2 = (8.78 * Math.pow(10 , -3)) * myGallonsUsed;        
    }

    /**
     * method to convert TOns to Pounds
     */
    public void convertTonsToPoundsCO2()
    {
        myPoundsCO2 = myGallonsUsed * 2204.62;
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the MyTonsCO2 private instance
     */
    public double getTonsCO2()
    {
        return myTonsCO2;
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the MyPoundsCO2 private instance
     */
    public double getPoundsCO2()
    {
        return myPoundsCO2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should tag your language, not that paradigm that it uses.

Answer (score 1):

Well not sure which particular programming language you are using but `calcTonsCO2()` method is defined on `CO2FootprintV1` class but you are trying to call it on a instance of `CO2FootprintV1Tester` class.

```
public class CO2FootprintV1
 {
    .......
public void calcTonsCO2()
{
    myTonsCO2 = (8.78 * Math.pow(10 , -3)) * myGallonsUsed;

}
  ....
}
```

You are calling

```
CO2FootprintV1Tester footprint = new CO2FootprintV1Tester();
footprint.calcTonsCO2();
```

It should rather be

```
CO2FootprintV1 footprint = new CO2FootprintV1();
footprint.calcTonsCO2();
```

Comment: So whats do i do then?